# Neo4jClient NeoException OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when querying in C#

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

When running a Cypher Match on a node with hundreds of thousands of entires, returning the results As a class, I get an OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error before processing the first row in the IEnumerable returned. It is acting as if the Neo4jClient is actually trying to hydrate the entire result set in memory before returning any rows. Is this the intended behavior? Why does't it stream the rows since it declares the interface as IEnumerable rather than IList? Is there another way to get the data as a stream?

Sample query:

```
foreach (var res in client
    .Cypher
    .Match("(bigNode:Some_Big_Node)")
    .Return(bigNode => bigNode.As<BigNode>()).Results)
{
    //Never gets here
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the intended behaviour, otherwise we wouldn't have the `UseJsonStreaming` flag (default = `true`) :) - I also think it's not passing the right header for streaming - which can be fixed, so I'll probably do that now and publish a new version for you to see if it solves it.

Comment: Right, 1.1.0.14 of the client is available now, please try and see how it goes...

Comment: If you run the Cypher query in the Neo4j browser directly what happens? A java heap space OOM error?